# Differential equation $y''+(y')^2+1=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I’m trying to solve this equation but at the end I’m stuck and can’t reach the answer. I use the substitutions $u=y'$ and $y''=du/dx$:

$$du/dx+u^2+1=0, \\ -du/(u^2+1)=dx, \\ -\arctan(u)=x+c$$

Here I don’t know how to go on. The answer should be $$y=\ln|\cos(c_1-x)|+c_2$$

Comment: The first two terms also occur in an exponential derivative. With that idea the equation becomes $(e^y)''+e^y=0$.

Comment: as a side note rewritting $y=y_0+\ln|\cos(x-x_0)|$ gives more meaning to the constants.

Answer (score 3):

From $-\arctan(u) = x+c$ we find that $u = \tan(-x + c).$

Now replace $u$ with $y'$, i.e. $y' = \tan(-x+c)$.

We integrate to find $y$ (rewrite tan in terms of sin and cosine, make the substitution $v = \cos(-x+c)$).

This gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''+(y')^2+1=0$$
$$u'+u^2+1=0$$
This is [Riccati's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) substitute $y'=u=\dfrac {f'}{f}=(\ln f)'$:
$$f''+f=0$$
$$\implies f=c_1\cos x +c_2 \sin x$$
$$e^y=c_1\cos x +c_2 \sin x$$
As Lutz Lehmann pointed in the comment. You can  also multiply by $e^y$ the DE:
$$y''+(y')^2+1=0$$
$$e^yy''+e^y(y')^2+e^y=0$$
$$(e^y)''+e^y=0$$
This is a second order linear DE.

Answer (score 0):

In order not to lose physical dimension of curvature we take $a=1$ in:

$$ \frac{y''}{1+y^{'2}}=\frac{-1}{a}$$

Let $ y'= \tan \phi, y^{''}= \sec^2 \phi\cdot \phi'~$ ; plugging in and integrating

$$ \phi^{'} = -\frac{1}{a},~\phi = c_1-\frac{x}{a},~ \tan\phi = \frac{dy}{dx}=\tan(c_1- \frac{x}{a});$$

$$ y= \log\sec(\frac{x}{a}-c_1) + c_2 $$

Setting arbitrary boundary condition  $~c_2= - \log ~y_1$ and for a symmetric boundary condition $c_1=0$ ,we have

$$ y=y_1 ~\log \sec \left( \frac{x}{a}\right)$$

that essentially agrees with the required result.

This is btw, the bounded shape taken by chainette cable of variable section and [Uniform strength](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/chainettedegaleresistance/chainettedegaleresistance.shtml#:%7E:text=The%20catenary%20of%20equal%20strength%20is%20the%20shape%20taken%20by,any%20point%20than%20in%20another.)